# How to access device drivers via Java in Android OS?

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, linux-device-driver

I’m creating an Android app that requires access to device drivers of Broadcomm’s Single Chip (integrated Wifi+Bluetooth+FM) chip URL: http://www.broadcom.com/products/Wireless-LAN/802.11-Wireless-LAN-Solutions/BCM4334.

Broadcomm has supposedly allowed access to the device drivers on Android OS ,and made their implementation open.

The functionality of the App, is irrelevant.

1)  What is the best way, in detail to access device drivers via Java in Android?

2)  Is using JNI to access device drivers a good approach?

3)  Is using the NDK necessary or is the SDK sufficient, since I’m just accessing device drivers & not actually writing native code?

4)  Any other important advice while I’m going down this path?

Also please be kind enough to respond only if you have developed similar applications or an expert , I don’t want to end up with 50 different opinions that will confuse me.

Thanks a million.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BCM4334 is a Wi-fi/BT combo chip, it doesn't include 3G modem.

I'm not sure what you mean by "accessing device driver", Wi-fi is exposed via the android.net.wifi, bluetooth - via android.bluetooth, and this is really the best way to use Wi-fi and BT on Android - via public API. Again, it is not clear to me what you want to do with the driver, but most likely your app doesn't have permissions to do anything useful anyway.

Different drivers have different interfaces, for example Wi-fi driver is controlled via IOCTL-based WE API (which would require native code), but there is also a set of command line tools (wireless tools) that can be used from pure Java, so there are multiple options depending on what you want to achieve.

But I want to reiterate that Android provides public API for both Wi-fi and BT and my advice is to use Android API, not low-level driver interface.

Comment: Yes the Broadcomm chip does not have 3G. 
However as I mentioned the functionality of the application is irrelevant to the questions, therefore you cannot suggest me to use the Android Bluetooth or Wifi APIs, If I wanted I would!
I asked three clear & distinct questions:
1) What is the best way, in detail to access device drivers via Java in Android?
2) Is using JNI to access device drivers a good approach?
3) Is using the NDK necessary or is the SDK sufficient, since I’m just accessing device drivers & not actually writing native code?

Comment: Please try to read my answer again - "Different drivers have different interfaces, for example Wi-fi driver is controlled via IOCTL-based WE API (which would require native code)". Bluetooth driver are also controlled via IOCTL-based HCI API. There is no direct way to send IOCTL from Java, so native code and JNI are required.

Comment: Ok given your answer , what is the best approach to "communicate" with drivers such as the FM driver which is present on Broadcomm but does not have a Android/Java package. I basically need to write a  Java/JNI wrapper to access FM driver on broadcomm chip? 1) What are the steps (how can i see the driver in the Android file system?) 2) What specific tools due I need, ndk? 3) Can you give me a detailed step by step on how to investigate & start this process? Thanks

Comment: It depends on how the driver is implemented. I believe some FM tuners provide V4L interface -  http://linuxtv.org/downloads/v4l-dvb-apis/radio.html but it looks like BCM tuners are controlled via HCI - see https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_frameworks_base/blob/froyo/core/jni/android_hardware_fm.cpp Another potential problem is audio stream routing, FM audio output must be somehow routed to the speaker - this depends on the architecture of your device.

Comment: I looked at the links briefly , it looks like were on the right track, Thanks. Now the issue regarding the NDK, should I be able to send HCI commands via JNI to the driver? Or in fact communicate to the driver via Java & JNI regardless of the protocol, without righting native code that sends the commands? Thanks